# Creating a new ArrayPagerAdapter with variety of Fragments

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to create an ArrayAdapter similar to the sample shown in the readme at this github page https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager. I have a variety of Fragments that I want to pass into an ArrayPagerAdapter instead of just one like in the example. I'm confused on how desc.getTitle is supposed to be passed in into the newly created instance of the Fragment in the example. Also how would I be able to do this same thing using android.app.Fragment to create a new instances of  Fragments? I have posted my code below I have an error on newInstance();

```
static class SimplePagerAdapter extends ArrayPagerAdapter<android.app.Fragment>{



    public SimplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                              ArrayList<PageDescriptor> descriptors) {
        super(fragmentManager, descriptors);
    }

    @Override
    protected android.app.Fragment createFragment(PageDescriptor desc) {

        Fragment newFragment = new JudgeMainFragment();

        return(android.app.Fragment.newInstance(desc.getTitle()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused on how desc.getTitle is supposed to be passed in into the newly created instance of the Fragment in the example

Your code is different from what I have in the project `README` and will not work, as `Fragment` has no `newInstance()` method. The `README` is showing an `EditorFragment`, specifically [the `EditorFragment` from the sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/pager/demo/EditorFragment.java). `EditorFragment` implements a `newInstance()` method, using the arguments `Bundle` to get the title into the fragment:

```
package com.commonsware.cwac.pager.demo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final String KEY_TITLE="title";

  static EditorFragment newInstance(String title) {
    EditorFragment frag=new EditorFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putString(KEY_TITLE, title);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);
    EditText editor=(EditText)result.findViewById(R.id.editor);

    editor.setHint(getTitle());

    return(result);
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return(getArguments().getString(KEY_TITLE));
  }
}
```

Note that there is no requirement for the fragment to know its title, but if you *want* the fragment to know its title, use the arguments `Bundle`, such as via a `newInstance()`-style factory method.

> Also how would I be able to do this same thing using android.app.Fragment to create a new instances of Fragments?

You wouldn't, because `Fragment` itself is fairly useless on its own. You create subclasses of `Fragment` to implement your pages, the way you do any fragment in Android.

> I have a variety of Fragments that I want to pass into an ArrayPagerAdapter instead of just one like in the example

You would need to know, based on the `PageDescriptor`, how to create the right fragment instance. That might be via an `int` or something in your custom `PageDescriptor` implementation, that you then use with a `switch` in `createFragment()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering that cleared up a lot. Only thing that is still a little cloudy for me now is what type to return in createFragment. In my code I have tried returning a Fragment and  android.app.Fragment  from createFragment and each gives me an error when trying to do so. The variety of Fragments I am trying to create using createFragment work perfectly fine when I call newInstance on them and return them in the getItem method of the FragmentPagerAdapter I currently have set up. Is this similar to how createFragment is supposed to work?

Comment: @Blaine: "each gives me an error when trying to do so" -- I can't really help you without knowing the error. Given your propensity for typing in the fully-qualified `android.app.Fragment`, my guess that [you are using the wrong `ArrayPagerAdapter` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager#choosing-the-package), but that is just a guess.

Comment: I have continued this in another question I asked at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093955/dynamically-adding-and-removing-tabs-using-arraypageradapter. Thanks for all the help so far.